# Findind the state of rich:collapsiblePanel on change event

Tags: javascript, richfaces

How to get the current state of `rich:collapsiblePanel` either extended or collapsed

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel header="Search" switchType="client" id="searchId" onswitch="checkState();">
Panel To show the Data
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
```

My JavaScript code is

```
function checkState() {
//Here how to get the current state
var st = #{rich:element('searchId')}.isExpanded();
alert(st);
}
```

Updated my Java Script but i'm getting the below error. We are using 4.3.4 Jars
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).isExpanded is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RichFaces.component("formId:panelId").isExpanded()
```

Read the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-collapsiblePanel-JavaScript_API).

EDIT: for versions up to 4.5.4:

```
RichFaces.component("formId:panelId").activeItem == "true"
```

Comment: i'm getting an error Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).isExpanded is not a function.

Comment: If you're not using the latest version of RichFaces you should say so right away, I've edited the answer.

Comment: When i tried to use  `alert(#{rich:element('searchId')}.activeItem)` i'm getting "undefined"  and `#{rich:element('searchId')}.activeItem == "true"` always returnung `false`

Comment: You are not following my suggestions. `rich:element` is for finding HTML elements, not RichFaces components (i.e. JavaScript objects), use `rich:component` for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finalli i got the difference between rich:component, rich:element and rich:clientId.